# Not able to fetch data in flutter from local web server

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to fetch data from a web server running on http://localhost:5050 and print it. At first it gave me a Socket Exception, so I looked it up and looks like you're supposed to replace "localhost" with your computer's IP address, so I did that, and now when I fetch it, it just seems to be... stuck? I have a print statement after the request but it doesn't print anything, no error, no output.. nothing. I'm using a Physical device, Here's my code:

```dart
class AllFlights extends StatefulWidget {
  const AllFlights({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AllFlightsState createState() => _AllFlightsState();
}

class _AllFlightsState extends State<AllFlights> {

  Future<void> getAllFlights() async {
    try {
      log("here");
      final res = await http.get(Uri.parse("http://192.168.8.100:5050/iflive/atc")); //fetch data -- gets stuck here
      log(res.body); // "log" statement, imported from dart:developer

    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: ElevatedButton(child: Text("All Flights",), onPressed: getAllFlights,),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note: *if it matters, the web server is running in a Docker container on port 5050 mapped to port 5050 on the host.*

EDIT: I just noticed that a solid 2-3 mins after calling the api, it gives me a Socket Exception: `[log] SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = 10.0.2.2, port = 44046`

Is this normal?

Comment: Since the web server is running in a Docker container on port 5050 mapped to port 5050 on the host why are you using port 5051?

Uri.parse("http://localhost:5050/iflive/atc") should work. If not try using postman and see what response you receive to your Get request

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo on my side while I was typing out the question, the actual code does have the proper port (5050)

Comment: Are you sure it is not a server-side problem?

Comment: @MichailHighkhan Fetching data from Postman and the browser works fine

Comment: FYI please don't add "solved", but accept an answer - even if it's your own

Answer (score 0):

Update: I was able to fix this by using adb (Android Debug Bridge) .

`adb reverse tcp:5050 tcp:5050`

this command routes your phone's requests on port 5050 to your computer's port 5050. Now you can just make requests to localhost directly instead on your computer's IP. The first port argument is your phone's port and second is your computer's.

example: `adb reverse tcp:5000 tcp:5050` will map port 5000 on your phone to 5050 on your computer.

Have a nice day everyone!

Comment: project has opened on my phone, but debug messages are not being printed on terminal